# How to merge two dataframes with different length and one is a subset of the other

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`.
`df1` contains a `member_ID` and a `result_id`
`df2` contains a `member_ID` and a `result_id`

However, in `df1` I have 1000 rows, in `df2` I have 1200 rows. The `df1` contains every row in `df2` plus 200 other rows.

I need `df3`, containing `member_ID` and `result_ID`, 
which contains all 1200 rows, and if there is a result_id in `df1`, then the value of `df1` should be used, while if there is no result_id in `df1` (for the remaining 200 rows), the result_ID in `df2` should be used.

When merged, the df will consist of the 1000 matching rows only.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Tilsight check if my solution works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package and do a `anti_join` to get the additional results contained in `df2`and then do a `rbind` to bind all in one data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
df_tmp <- anti_join(df1 ,df2, by=member_ID)
df3 <-rbind(df_tmp, df1)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I have an additional question, same data frames, df1 contains 1000 rows, df2 contains 1200 rows. Let us say that df1 is not exactly a subset of df2 (it turned out to be the case so I have more than 1200 rows now.
I need to create df3 with 1200 rows, if the member_ID of df2 = member_ID of df1, then use result_ID of df1, if there is no match, then use the result_ID of df2, but I need members from df2 only.

Comment: @Tilsight I think it should work anyway because you are taking all `df1` and the differences between `df1` and `df2`. To make sure that there are no duplicates you could add an additional step at the end and do: `df3 <- unique(df3)`

Comment: Thanks, Barbara, but unfortunately there was no duplication. I am checking the anti join now.

Comment: @Tilsight I have edited the answer now, try with `df_tmp <- anti_join(df1 ,df2, by=member_ID)`

Comment: I understand the logic now. We take the "difference" by member ID to get those who do not appear in df1 and add it later to df1. It is getting better but still not perfect. I will get back to you what was wrong.

Comment: Can I just replace result_ID in df2 with result_ID in df1 for maching member_ID somehow? Like if member_ID of df1 = member_ID of df2 THEN result_ID of df 1 => result_ID of df2, ELSE do nothing.

Comment: @Tilsight what is wrong with the results?

Comment: It still returns more rows than 1200. I looked up the "duplication" with outer, left, right, etc merge, tried all but they also returned different results.
And I can not ask more questions because the clever boys marked as a duplicate while it is clearly not.... thanks ...

Comment: @Tilsight could you post a `dput()` of your data frames? Another thing you could try is this `df_tmp <- anti_join(df1 ,df2, by=member_ID)  df_tmp2 <- inner_join(df1 ,df2, by=member_ID)  df3 <- rbind(df_tmp, df_tmp2)`